# Silverlight Multiple Command Binding in MVVM

Tags: mvvm, silverlight-4.0, icommand

I am starting to build Silverlight application using MVVM.
I have button on a XAML page to enable saving of data on its click I have written following code.

```
 <Button Content="Save" Grid.Column="2" Grid.Row="3"
                    Command="{Binding Path=SaveCourse}"/>
```

and in the view model class i have implemnets the following code;

```
public class SaveCurrentCourse : ICommand
        {
            private MaintenanceFormViewModel viewModel;
            public SaveCurrentCourse(MaintenanceFormViewModel viewModel)
            {
                this.viewModel = viewModel;
                this.viewModel.PropertyChanged += (s, e) =>
                    {
                        if (this.CanExecuteChanged != null)
                        {
                            this.CanExecuteChanged(this, new EventArgs());
                        }
                    };   
            }
            public bool CanExecute(object parameter)
            {
                return this.viewModel.CurrentCourse != null;
            }

            public event EventHandler CanExecuteChanged;

            public void Execute(object parameter)
            {
                this.viewModel.SaveCourseImplementation();
            }
        }
```

Which kind of works for my save command.
The question I have is if there are multiple buttons on the page then do I have to write the same code as above for each of the button? 
Can any body suggest a better way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Microsoft's patterns & practices team offers a library called Prism that simplifies this somewhat. http://compositewpf.codeplex.com/

They provide a class called `DelegateCommand` that implements `ICommand` and allows you to pass the method name that you would like executed.

```
public class Test {
    public Test(){
        SomeCommand = new DelegateCommand<object>(DoSomething);
    }
    public DelegateCommand<object> SomeCommand { get; private set;}
    private void DoSomething(object parameter){
        //Do some stuff
    }
}
```

You can then bind your controls Command property to `SomeCommand`. You can also bind CommandParameter to something and it will be passed in as the parameter to the DoSomething method. An additional constructor for DelegateCommand allows you to pass a CanExecute method as a second parameter, that will enable/disable the control. If you need to update the enabled/disabled status of the control you can call DelegateCommand's `RaiseCanExecuteChanged()` method.

```
public class Test {
    public Test(){
        SomeCommand = new DelegateCommand<object>(DoSomething, (enabled) => CanSave());
    }
    public DelegateCommand<object> SomeCommand { get; private set;}
    private void DoSomething(object parameter){
        //Do some stuff
    }
    private bool CanSave(){
        if(/*test if the control should be enabled */)
            return true;
        else
            return false;
    }
    private void DoABunchOfStuff(){
        //something here means the control should be disabled
        SomeCommand.RaiseCanExecuteChanged();
    }
}
```

Comment: BTW, all that code is from memory, and obviously the if statement won't compile, but it should be pretty close.

Comment: Thanks Adam will try your solution.